# FireBaseRecyclerOptions with different modals (androidStudio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

i need 2 diferentes layouts (recyclerview) for my app i'm using Firebase, the problem is when i trying to use another modal and another Adapter for the firebase i got an error.

Required type:

FirebaseRecyclerOptions

<PTsModal>

Provided:

FirebaseRecyclerOptions

<TRsModal>

I Don't want to change from ModalTRs to ModalPTs i want to use both for diferent layouts is there any solution?

I dind't find any solution in the internet

PtsModal (same as TrsModal with other variables)

```
public class PTsModal
{
PTsModal()
{

}
public PTsModal(String titulo, String desc, String imgurl)
{
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}

public String getTitulo()
{
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo)
{
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getDesc()
{
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc)
{
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getImgurl()
{
    return imgurl;
}

public void setImgurl(String imgurl)
{
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}

String titulo, desc, imgurl;
```

}

Adapter

```
public class ProgramAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PTsModal,ProgramAdapter.myViewHolder>
{

/**
 * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
 * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
 *
 * @param options
 */
public ProgramAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PTsModal> options)
{
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PTsModal model)
{
    holder.titulo.setText(model.getTitulo());
    holder.desc.setText(model.getDesc());

    Glide.with(holder.img1.getContext()).load(model.getImgurl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused)
            .into(holder.img1);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.box,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ImageView img1;
    TextView titulo, desc;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        img1 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagem_box);
        titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
    }
}
```

}
pts.activity

```
public class Boticas_PT extends AppCompatActivity
   {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgramAdapter  programadapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    //Indicar Titulo, descricao e imagem(mesmo tamanho)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.boticas_pt);
        //Menu e recyclerview
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.navigration_open, R.string.navigration_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //Ligação à base de dados
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PTsModal> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PTsModal>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PtsBoticas"), PTsModal.class).build();
        programadapter = new ProgramAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(programadapter);
    }
    //Base de dados buscar dados
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        programadapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void  onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        programadapter.stopListening();
    }
```

Trs.activity

```
{
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProgramAdapter  programadapter2;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationView navigationView;
//Indicar Titulo, descricao e imagem(mesmo tamanho)

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.boticas_tr);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigration_open, R.string.navigration_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //Ligação à base de dados
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TRsModal> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TRsModal>()
            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TRsBoticas"), TRsModal.class).build();
    **programadapter2 = new ProgramAdapter(options);**//here i got error
    recyclerView.setAdapter(programadapter2);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: i can adapt this model and pass the 4 text to the textview description... but is not a great solution

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).